# How to inherit from base provider (not the provider factory)?

Tags: angularjs, prototypal-inheritance, angularjs-provider

Say I have this base provider:

```
angular.module('app').provider('BaseClient', function () {
    this.setSomething = function (something) {
        // Store `something` somewhere
        return this;
    };
});
```

And now these 2 other sub-providers:

```
angular.module('app').provider('ClientA', function () {
    this.$get = function () {
        return {
            foo: function () {
                console.log('FOO', /* Read `something`, needs to output 'aaa' */);
            }
        }
    };
});

angular.module('app').provider('ClientB', function () {
    this.$get = function () {
        return {
            bar: function () {
                console.log('BAR', /* Read `something`, needs to output 'bbb' */);
            }
        }
    };
});

angular.module('app').config(function (clientAProvider, clientBProvider) {
    clientAProvider.setSomething('aaa');
    clientBProvider.setSomething('bbb');
});
```

How do I make `ClientA` and `ClientB` inherit the provider section of `BaseClient` in such a way that I can call `clientAProvider.setSomething('aaa')` and `clientBProvider.setSomething('bbb')` and store that value per provider, while using the same `setSomething` implementation?

I have a bunch of these providers (more than these 2) where the provider section is always the same, the configuration implementation is always the same but the factory section of those providers are different.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inject `BaseClientProvider` into your `ClientA` provider.

Full code is here [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jzmnSvTHDZR7wYPMkU1A)

---

```
app.provider('BaseClient', function() {
  this.config = {
    something: null
  };

  this.setSomething = function(something) {
    this.config.something = something;
    return this;
  };

  this.$get = function() {};
});

app.provider('ClientA', ['BaseClientProvider', function(BaseClientProvider) {
  var self = this;
  angular.extend(self, BaseClientProvider);
  self.$get = function() {
    return {
      foo: function() {
        console.log('FOO', self.config.something);
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: I'm really sorry but looking at the answer I just realized I made the wrong question. Please give me a few minutes to fix the question.

Comment: Updated. Sorry again.

Comment: I add  `angular.extend(this, BaseClientProvider);` into `ClientA` provider, It's work.

Comment: Never thought of using `angular.extend` like that :) I can't really test this right now, but are you sure it works to the point where each client provider will have it's own independent configuration values? That's what the `self` is for, correct?

Comment: I'm sure. You could see my plunker link.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working exactly as expected, see the full plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/wTwHxBvOaTtmVFlKK1IC?p=preview - The problem is `angular.extend` which does not do a deep copy. Using `angular.merge` from v1.4 solves the issue, but I can't use that just yet. Another way to solve the problem is to store each configurable variable at `this.variable` instead of `this.config.variable`. This also solves it. Or am I missing something on your solution and it should work as you posted it?

Comment: I just remember I'm using `lodash` and I have access to `merge`.

Comment: But now that I'm implementing this on my real code, I've come to the conclusion that I wanted something slightly different, which I'm not sure it's possible. I'm exposing `this.config` to the public and you could just inject the provider and change `something` by directly changing the `config` object or through the `setSomething` function. I'd prefer if you could only do that through the `setSomething` function.

Comment: I edit from `angular.extend(self, BaseClientProvider);` to `angular.extend(self, angular.copy(BaseClientProvider));` in your full [plunkr] (http://plnkr.co/edit/AeAI92i26JOPwItX3Tmn?p=preview). Is it working exactly as expected?

Comment: Yes, that works too, but I'll use `_.merge` instead, it's simpler. What about the problem I described in the previous comment. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what's your problem.

Comment: When you inject the provider in the config phase, you can call `setSomething` to set the value of `something`, but you can also just change `config.something` directly. Any way to avoid that and only have the set method changing the value? But still having different config objects per provider.

Comment: My original problem was solved by this solution and nobody else came up with a better/different one. I'm accepting this as the correct answer and create a new one for the other problem. See here if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30970343/how-to-prevent-direct-access-to-variables-on-this-when-inheriting-from-a-base Thank you.